# Typescript: Intersection Type any object and options

Tags: typescript

I'd like to make type with any props and option must be number

```
type PropsWithOption = object & {option?:number}
const props:PropsWithOption = {anyProp1:'',anyProp2:'',option:5}
```

However, this makes error and the type PropsWithOption should be an empty object or object with only option `{}`
`{option:number}`

How can I solve it?

thanks

```
type PropsWithOption = object & {option?:number}
// I tried below codes also, but they throws same errors 
// type PropsWithOption = Object & {option?:number}
// type PropsWithOption = {} & {option?:number}
const props:PropsWithOption = {anyProp1:'',anyProp2:'',option:5}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

```
type PropsWithOption = {
  option?: number;
  [prop: string]: any;
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwOoEtgAsDyZjoIB2UAvFAN4BQUUSBxA-AFxRECuAtgEYRwDcNKAG0wiMK2TA46IgHMAuqwCGREIIC+gqgGNiUqGKQBGVvCRpMufIRLkKUVSHNhTUAOTuANI7UuATKyePvS2rACsUFpAA)